# Appbar scrolling behavior doesn't work when the content is scrolled programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, smooth-scrolling, android-appbarlayout

I have implemented the appbar scrolling behavior in my app and it worked sweetly just like the whatsapp app.

However the collapsing behavior only worked when i scroll it by touch, i.e. by using my finger to scroll. When i scroll the content programmatically, the content did scrolled, but the appbar remains in fully expanded state and does not collapse at all. No collapsing, just that the content is scrolled up.

Here's my code of my main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem                    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tab_text_2" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here my tab fragment in which the scrolling takes place:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".Tutorial">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            layout="@layout/panel1"/>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            layout="@layout/panel2"/>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            layout="@layout/panel3"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

*this fragment is in the viewPager of the mainlayout

Here's the method that i use to scroll the NestedScrollView

```
nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, panel3.getTop());
```

The contents of the NestedScrollView is pretty long and sufficient for me to scroll. I can achieve the "appbar collapsing" scrolling behavior when i scroll it by touch, but not programmatically. I tried replacing the NestedScrollView with RecyclerView but to no avail.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have same issue did you solve it?

Comment: @MohammadSommakia I can't solve it even after a long while searching for the solution ;) Maybe no one cares about it as it is just a minor detail. But for perfectionists like us, it might be a pain tho...